# Would Nautical superstitions fall under mythology and folklore?

Tags: discussion, scope

As long as humankind was at sea there have been a lot of superstitions in and around the sea.

Some of the nautical/sailors superstitions are time worn and some are relatively new.

The version of heaven for sailors who sailed more than 50 years at sea was called fiddler's green, this superstition is from the 19th century

Sirens on the other hand, are mythological creatures who appear in the Odyssey, where the hero Odysseus, wishing to hear the sirens' seductive and destructive song, must protect himself and his crew by having his fellow sailors tie him to the mast and then stop their own ears with wax.

And if so should a tag be created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an interesting question about maritime folklore, please go ahead and ask it. I see no reason why it wouldn't be on topic.

Also, do not worry much about the tags. For a question about [Fiddler's Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler%27s_Green), for example, you can use the existing [afterlife](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afterlife) and [superstition](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superstition) tags. We could also create [maritime-folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maritime-folklore) (or something similar). However, that needs to happen when you post the question or afterwards, as tags cannot be created in isolation.