# Should there be a Canaanite tag?

Tags: feature-request

I asked a question today about Canaanite mythology and was surprised to discover there was no Canaanite tag. Is there another tag that I missed that covers this or should there be a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Canaanite tag you are welcome to do so, the easiest way to do so is to ask a Canaanite mythology specific question and make the tag when adding the applicable tags to your question (the question is there but if the tag will be used much is another story).

I want to refer you to my [question on Meta](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/453/would-nautical-superstitions-fall-under-mythology-and-folklore) which asked a similar kind of question and @Yannis' answer is (I think) sufficient to answer your inquiry.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no Canaanite tag. There is a little-used Middle East one.  (I added a description to it.)

Searching finds about 22 references to "Canaanite" mostly in answers, but some in questions, so Middle East could probably cover it.